# Retrieve value of a spinner after validation

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I have a problem to retrieve the value of a spinner when I want to validate my insertion.

here is how I fill my spinner :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrayList;
myArrayList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < studentList.length(); i++) {
JSONObject c = studentList.getJSONObject(i);
String id = c.getString("id");
String name = c.getString("name");
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("id", id);
map.put("name", name);
myArrayList.add(map);
}
```

and after :

```
SpinnerAdapter studentAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
MyActivity.this, myArrayList,
R.layout.student, new String[] { "id", "name"},
new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name });
mySpinner.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
```

When I click on my button "OK", and I get the value of the spinner with

```
mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I get :

> {id=2, name=Smith}

But i'm sure there is another method **to retrieve only the name**, but how? By getting the adapter with the spinner? It is my problem...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object the `Spinner` is giving you is a HashMap. Cast it as such, and then extract the value the way you normally would:

```
String studentName = ((HashMap)mySpinner.getSelectedItem()).get("name");
```

Another option: rather than using `ArrayList<HashMap>` to populate your `Spinner`, you may want to do it with  `ArrayList<Student>` (assuming `Student` is a class you already have at your disposal). You can then cast the currently-selected object to `Student` and use it as you please:

```
String studentName = ((Student)mySpinner.getSelectedItem()).name;
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark this answer as accepted so others can quickly see what fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

> i'm sure there is another method to retrieve only the name, but how?

You can use an OnItemSelectedListener which will always have the user's current choice:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
    // Do with name as you please
}
```

Or you could use the same technique with [`getSelectedView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#getSelectedView%28%29) to only get the name after your validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
String data="{id=2, name=Smith}";//you retrieved 
String array[]=data.split("name=");//split in values of '**id=2,** ' and '**Smith**'
String name=array[array.length-1];  //take last value
```

You will have 'Smith' in name variable. Not prefered but if no choice then use it